# Cannot set width and height of cloned element

Tags: javascript, dom, element, clone

I cloned an image element using JS. I can move it around by setting the left and top attributes of the clone. However I cannot change the size.

```
var sprite_org = "WEs1";
var sprites = new Array(7);

var org = document.getElementById(sprite_org);
sprites[0] = org;

for (var i=1; i<7; i++) {
    let clone = org.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute( 'id', "Sprite" + i );
    org.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    sprites[i] = document.getElementById("Sprite"+i);
    sprites[i].style.top = "0px";
    sprites[i].style.width = "500px";
}
```

Comment: How do you set its initial size? Do you use styles or `<img/>` attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning this up a bit.

```
for (var i=1; i<7; i++) {
    let clone = org.cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute( 'id', "Sprite" + i );
    clone.style.top = "0px";
    clone.style.width = "500px";
    sprites[i] = clone;
    org.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Also images have width and height "attributes" not just the css styling of them:

```
clone.width = 500;
clone.height = 300;
```

Comment: thank but this still doesn't work. i can consosle.log("sprites[i].width") or even style.width and the properties actually do get saved, they just don't affect anything

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with

```
for (var i=1; i<7; i++) {
    sprites[i] = org.cloneNode(true);
    sprites[i].style.left = i*200+"px";;
    document.getElementById("WEbggroup").appendChild(sprites[i]);
}
```